# Обновление блока без перезагрузки страницы + недочет

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите как реализовать обновление `<div>` блока. Обычное обновление без перезагрузки блока я нашел, но теперь вопрос, при выделение текста в том блоке, где какой либо текст(обновляемый) выделение текста соответственно пропадает, так как блок не стоит на месте а обновляется. Но много сайтов, где есть обновление блока без перезагрузки страницы и при выделение этого блока, любого в нем текста, выделение не пропадает. Как это делается ?

Мой код:

```
<div id="content"></div>


function show()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "time.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#content").html(html);
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            show();
            setInterval('show()',1000);
        });
```

Comment: "Но много сайтов, ... блока без перезагрузки ... выделение ... не пропадает" - например? В качестве простейшего решения можно предложить перед перезаписью содержимого блока проверять на идентичность содержимого с пришедшим html.

Comment: @kolpak, как это выглядит в виде кода? если не соизволит у вас большого труда, то прошу пожалуйста напишите код.

Comment: я думаю у "многих сайтов" блоки добавляются, а не переписываются

Comment: Советую использовать WebSockets, или как написали выше

Comment: Что-то вроде if ($("#content").html() != html) { $("#content").html(html) }, с оглядкой на то, что эти два куска текста нужно будет причесать до общего вида, так как возможны различия в количестве пробелов/переносов и т.п. И ещё, вы абсолютно не верно применили слово "соизволит".

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните как.

Comment: В интернете очень много примеров! Если вы ноль в этом, то не ищите тут халявных помощников! Или нанимайте человека для помощи или ищите в интернете примеры и делайте сами.

Comment: @malina95 уууу... а вы обратили внимание, что я не топикстартер?